# Prove a tensor product's component is zero

Tags: tensor-products

Suppose we have $R$-module elements $m\in M,n\in N$ with $m\otimes n=0\in M\underset{R}\otimes N$. Is it necessarily true that $m=0$ or $n=0$? I can't seem to prove it using the basic tensor product relations.

Edit: Okay, what about if $M$ and $N$ are vector spaces?

Comment: For the vector space case, it is indeed true that $m$ or $n$ must be zero. For assume they are not. Then pick $f\in M^*$, $g \in N^*$ with $f(m)=g(n)=1$ (which we can do because we are in a vector space and so for example we can extend $m$ to a basis of $M$ and define $f$ to be 0 on the other basis elements). Then $f\otimes g:M\otimes N\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ sending $x\otimes y$ to $f(x)g(y)$ is a linear map which is not zero on $m\otimes n$, and hence $m\otimes n$ is not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $2 \otimes 1$ in $Z \otimes (Z/2)$.

Comment: By $Z/2$, do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? And if yes, do you claim $2 \otimes \bar 1$ is really _zero_ in $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?